# Scala macro annotation expansion order

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

```
@Macro
class X {
  @AnotherMacro
  def y = ...
}
```

Will the class be transformed first (and able to modify `@AnotherMacro`) or will the method? Is this guaranteed?